# GridView SelectedIndexChanged scroll into view to a DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have a `GridView` that displays a small amount of information about multiple users. In this `GridView`, I have a button that will display all of the information about the selected user inside a `DetailsView` below the `GridView`. The problem is, if I don't search for a specific user, I get a list of over 200 people and the `GridView` is extremely long. This makes the end-user have to scroll to the bottom of the page, which is very annoying. I have been reading about a `ScrollIntoView` function but I don't think that it is related to a DetailsView. I also read that I can use JavaScript to potentially get the results that I am looking for. I am not sure what the best approach is for this, but any help would be very much appreciated. I have an empty `SelectedIndexChanged` method that was generated by Visual Studio when I double clicked on the button. If I do end up going with the JavaScript route, where would I insert the code for this? Would it go in the aspx.cs page or just the aspx page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a work around to get this working properly. I created a new button that the user can press that will scroll to the top of the `DetailsView`. It was quite simple, but it will work for what we do. I created an empty `span` tag above the `DetailsView` and used `<input type="button" value="Scroll to Person" onclick="document.getElementById('topOfPerson').scrollIntoView();" />` for the button.

Answer (score 0):

If all the clicks of the GridView point to the same place on the page, you could do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#targetID").offset().top
        }, "medium");
    });
</script>
```

If you load the `DetailsView` with a PostBack, ypu can do this. Add a scriptmanager to the code behind.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ScrollToElement", "ScrollToElement('targetID')", true);
```

And then the matching JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ScrollToElement(id) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
        }, "medium");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Would the script code would go inside the aspx page or the aspx.cs?

Comment: The `ScriptManager` goes in the .cs in the method that would fill the `DetailsView`, the rest on the aspx